# JavaScript: ¿bucle infinito?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Estoy intentando recrear el juego "pasapalabra" para una entrega de programación, pero tengo un problema y es que no entiendo por qué se genera una especie de bucle infinito cuando el programa hace la segunda pasada de preguntas (para volver a mostrar aquellas a las que se les dio "pasapalabra")

Para reproducir el error del que os hablo, dadle "pasapalabra" a todas las letras, veréis que en la segunda pasada, a partir de la letra C/D comienza a trabarse toda la página...
Os dejo mi código aquí:

```js
const questions = [
    {
      letter: "a",
      answer: "abducir",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la A",
      question: ["Dicho de una supuesta criatura extraterrestre.", "Apoderarse de alguien"],
    },
    {
      letter: "b",
      answer: "bingo",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la B",
      question: ["Juego que ha sacado de quicio a todos los 'Skylabers' en las sesiones de precurso.", "Juego de la suerte, consiste en hacer 'LÍNEA' o..."],
    },
    {
      letter: "c",
      answer: "churumbel",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la C",
      question: ["Niño, crío, bebé.", "Crío, bebé, niño."],
    },
    {
      letter: "d",
      answer: "diarrea",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la D",
      question: ["Anormalidad en la función del aparato digestivo caracterizada por frecuentes evacuaciones y su consistencia líquida.", "Alteración intestinal caracterizado por la mayor frecuencia y fluidez."],
    },
    {
      letter: "e",
      answer: "ectoplasma",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la E",
      question: ["Gelatinoso y se encuentra debajo de la membrana plasmática.", "Los cazafantasmas medían su radiación", ""],
    },
    {
      letter: "f",
      answer: "facil",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la F",
      question: ["Que no requiere gran esfuerzo, capacidad o dificultad.", "Lo contrario a los ejercicios del pre-curso."],
    },
    {
      letter: "g",
      answer: "galaxia",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la G",
      question: ["Conjunto enorme de estrellas, polvo interestelar, gases y partículas.", "Una de las mayores estructuras del espacio."],
    },
    {
      letter: "h",
      answer: "harakiri",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la H",
      question: ["Suicidio ritual japonés por desentrañamiento.", "Ritual japonés de auto sacrificio realizado con un arma blanca y por honor."],
    },
    {
      letter: "i",
      answer: "iglesia",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la I",
      question: ["Templo cristiano.", "Institución cristiana."],
    },
    {
      letter: "j",
      answer: "jabali",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la J",
      question: ["Variedad salvaje del cerdo.", "Personaje 'Pumba' que sale en la película 'El Rey León'"],
    },
    {
      letter: "k",
      answer: "kamikaze",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la K",
      question: ["Persona que se juega la vida realizando una acción temeraria.", "Persona que se auto inmola."],
    },
    {
      letter: "l",
      answer: "licantropo",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la L",
      question: ["Hombre lobo.", "Que está afectado por licantropía."],
    },
    {
      letter: "m",
      answer: "misantropo",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la M",
      question: ["Persona que huye del trato con otras personas.", "Persona que siente gran aversión hacia las personas."],
    },
    {
      letter: "n",
      answer: "necedad",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la N",
      question: ["Demostración de poca inteligencia.", "Dicho o hecho propio de una persona necia."],
    },
    {
      letter: "ñ",
      answer: "señal",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Contiene la Ñ",
      question: ["Indicio que permite deducir algo de lo que no se tiene un conocimiento directo.", "Gesto que se hace para indicar algo."],
    },
    {
      letter: "o",
      answer: "orco",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la O",
      question: ["Humanoide fantástico de apariencia terrible y bestial, piel de color verde creada por el escritor Tolkien.", "Antónimo del ser de ficción 'elfo'."],
    },
    {
      letter: "p",
      answer: "protoss",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la P",
      question: ["Raza ancestral tecnológicamente avanzada que se caracteriza por sus grandes poderes psíonicos del videojuego StarCraft.", "Una de las 3 razas del videojuego StarCraft."],
    },
    {
      letter: "q",
      answer: "queso",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la Q",
      question: ["Producto obtenido por la maduración de la cuajada de la leche.", "Alimento favorito de los ratones."],
    },
    {
      letter: "r",
      answer: "raton",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la R",
      question: ["Roedor.", "Su alimento favorito es el queso."]
    },
    {
      letter: "s",
      answer: "stackoverflow",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la S",
      question: ["Comunidad salvadora de todo desarrollador informático.", "La mejor comunidad de internet."],
    },
    {
      letter: "t",
      answer: "terminator",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la T",
      question: ["Película del director James Cameron que consolidó a Arnold Schwarzenegger como actor en 1984", "'Hasta la vista baby'."],
    },
    {
      letter: "u",
      answer: "unamuno",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la U",
      question: ["Escritor y filósofo español de la generación del 98.", "Autor del libro 'Niebla'."],
    },
    {
      letter: "v",
      answer: "vikingos",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la V",
      question: ["Nombre dado a los miembros de los pueblos nórdicos originarios de Escandinavia.", "Famosos por sus incursiones y pillajes en Europa."],
    },
    {
      letter: "w",
      answer: "sandwich",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Contiene la W",
      question: ["Emparedado hecho con dos rebanadas de pan entre las cuales se coloca jamón y queso.", "Especie de bocadillo hecho con dos o más rodajas de pan."],
    },
    {
      letter: "x",
      answer: "botox",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Contiene la X",
      question: ["Toxina bacteriana utilizada en cirujía estética.", "Famosa capacidad para reducir la apariencia de arrugas faciales."],
    },
    {
      letter: "y",
      answer: "peyote",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Contiene la Y",
      question: ["Pequeño cáctus conocido por sus alcaloides psicoactivos", "Cáctus utilizado de forma ritual y medicinal por indígenas americanos."],
    },
    {
      letter: "z",
      answer: "zen",
      status: 0,
      questionTitle: "Con la Z",
      question: ["Escuela de budismo que busca la experiencia de la sabiduría más allá del discurso racional", "Movimiento budista que mantiene la mente abierta y una actitud de aceptación ante lo que se vive."],
    },
];

let gameQuestions = questions.slice();
let unansweredLetters = gameQuestions.length;
let score = 0;
let userEndGame = false;

let startButton = document.querySelector('.start-game-button');
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    showGame();
    showQuestions();
});

document.querySelector('.answer-input').addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector('.answer-button').click();
    }
});
document.querySelector('.answer-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < gameQuestions.length; i++) {
        if (gameQuestions[i].status === 0) {
            checkUserGuess(gameQuestions[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    document.querySelector('.answer-input').value = '';
    document.querySelector('.answer-input').focus();
    showQuestions();
});

const showQuestions = () => {
    do {
        for (let i = 0; i < gameQuestions.length; i++) {
            if (document.querySelector('.pasapalabra-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
                if (gameQuestions[i].status === 0) {
                    gameQuestions[i].status = 3;
                    addClassToLetters(questions, document.querySelector('.letters-list'));
                    showQuestions();
                }}));
            if (gameQuestions[i].status === 0) {
                document.querySelector('.question-title').innerHTML = gameQuestions[i].questionTitle;
                document.querySelector('.question-text').innerHTML = gameQuestions[i].question[(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2))];
                return;
            }
            if (userEndGame) {
                break;
            }
            if (timer === 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (gameQuestions.some(question => question.status === 0) && !userEndGame && timer > 0);
    if (gameQuestions.some(question => question.status === 3)) {
        gameQuestions = questions.slice();
        unansweredLetters = gameQuestions.length;
        removeIdleClass(questions, document.querySelector('.letters-list'));
        return showQuestions();
    } else {
        showAfterGame();
    }
}

const checkUserGuess = question => {
    let userGuess = document.querySelector('.answer-input').value.toLowerCase();
    if (userGuess === question.answer) {
        question.status = 1;
        unansweredLetters --;
        score += 10;
    } else {
        question.status = 2;
        unansweredLetters --;
        score -= 5;
        if (score < 0) {
            score = 0;
        }
    }
    addClassToLetters(questions, document.querySelector('.letters-list'));
}

const addClassToLetters = (questions, htmlList) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        let questionStatus = questions[i].status;
        let htmlLetter = htmlList.querySelector(`.letter:nth-child(${i + 1})`);
        if (questionStatus === 1) {
            htmlLetter.classList.add('correct');
        } else if (questionStatus === 2) {
            htmlLetter.classList.add('wrong');
        } else if (questionStatus === 3) {
            htmlLetter.classList.add('idle');
        }
    }
}

const removeIdleClass = (questions, htmlList) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        let questionStatus = questions[i].status;
        let htmlLetter = htmlList.querySelector(`.letter:nth-child(${i + 1})`);
        if (questionStatus === 3) {
            htmlLetter.classList.remove('idle');
            questions[i].status = 0;
        }
    }
}

let exitButton = document.querySelector('.end-game-button');
exitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    userEndGame = true;
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
    showAfterGame();
});

let timer = 150;
let timerInterval;
const startTimer = () => {
    timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
        timer--;
        document.querySelector('.timer').innerHTML = timer;
        if (timer === 0) {
            clearInterval(timerInterval);
            showAfterGame();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

const showGame = () => {
    document.querySelector('.pre-game').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.game').style.display = 'block';
    startTimer();
}
const showAfterGame = () => {
    document.querySelector('.game').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.after-game').style.display = 'block';
}
const showPreGame = () => {
    document.querySelector('.after-game').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.pre-game').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(28, 28, 28);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2rem;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.container .letters-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 2rem;
}
.container .letters-list li {
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: rgb(161, 161, 255);
    color: black;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
}
.container .letters-list li.correct {
    background-color: rgb(100, 255, 100);
}
.container .letters-list li.wrong {
    background-color: rgb(255, 100, 100);
}
.container .letters-list li.idle {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 100);
}
.container .scoreboard {
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: black;
    cursor: default;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: rgb(161, 161, 255);
}
.container .pre-game, .container .game, .container .after-game {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
.container .game, .container .after-game {
    display: none;
}


/* Pre game */
.container .pre-game h2 {
    margin-top: -10rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.container .pre-game p {
    margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}
.container .pre-game button {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 255);
    color: blanchedalmond;
    font-size: 19px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container .pre-game button:hover {
    color: rgb(100, 100, 255);
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
}


/* Game */
.container .game .answer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 40px;
}
.container .game .question {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container .game .question h2 {
    padding: 20px;
}
.container .game .question p {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.container .game button {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 255);
    color: blanchedalmond;
    font-size: 19px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
}
.container .game button:hover {
    color: rgb(100, 100, 255);
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
.container .game .end-game-button {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
.container .game input {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: rgb(197, 197, 255);
    color: black;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}



/* After game */
.container .after-game .after-game-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container .after-game-header h2 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.container .after-game-header button {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 255);
    color: blanchedalmond;
    font-size: 19px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.container .after-game-header button:hover {
    color: rgb(100, 100, 255);
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
.container .after-game .after-game-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.container .after-game-body h3 {
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.container .after-game-body p {
    color: blanchedalmond;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Pasapalabra</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>¡Pasapalabra!</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="container">
        <div class="letters-and-scoreboard">
            <ul class="letters-list">
                <li class="letter">A</li>
                <li class="letter">B</li>
                <li class="letter">C</li>
                <li class="letter">D</li>
                <li class="letter">E</li>
                <li class="letter">F</li>
                <li class="letter">G</li>
                <li class="letter">H</li>
                <li class="letter">I</li>
                <li class="letter">J</li>
                <li class="letter">K</li>
                <li class="letter">L</li>
                <li class="letter">M</li>
                <li class="letter">N</li>
                <li class="letter">Ñ</li>
                <li class="letter">O</li>
                <li class="letter">P</li>
                <li class="letter">Q</li>
                <li class="letter">R</li>
                <li class="letter">S</li>
                <li class="letter">T</li>
                <li class="letter">U</li>
                <li class="letter">V</li>
                <li class="letter">W</li>
                <li class="letter">X</li>
                <li class="letter">Y</li>
                <li class="letter">Z</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="scoreboard">
                <div class="timer">
                    150
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section class="pre-game">
            <h2>¡The famous Alphabet Game!</h2>
            <p>Try to answer as many questions as you can before the time runs out.</p>
            <p>You will have 150 seconds to do it.</p>
            <p>Each correct answer will give you 10 points, each wrong answer will take 5 points.</p>
            <p>¡Good luck!</p>
            <button class="start-game-button">Start Game</button>
        </section>

        <section class="game">
            <div class="game-questions">
                <div class="question">
                    <h2 class="question-title"></h2>
                    <p class="question-text"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input class="answer-input" type="text" placeholder="Type your answer...">
                    <button class="answer-button">Send answer</button>
                    <button class="pasapalabra-button">¡Pasapalabra!</button>
                    <button class="end-game-button">Exit game</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="after-game">
            <div class="after-game-header">
                <h2>¡Game Over!</h2>
                <button class="restart-game-button">Restart Game</button>
            </div>
            <div class="after-game-body">
                <div class="user-score">
                    <h3>Your score</h3>
                    <p class="user-score">0</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    </main>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias, llevo horas rompiéndome la cabeza con esto.

Comment: El código debes incluirlo en la pregunta. De todas maneras lo miré un poco y creo tu while sobra, no es para nada necesario

Comment: Código agregado a la pregunta, lo siento

Comment: Buena, pero me queda la otra duda, porque usas el while?? yo no lo veo necesario

Comment: Yo no usaría un while ya que puede hacer que el navegador se trabe. El código corre sobre un solo hilo, mejor usa `setTimeout`, `setInterval` y eventos. No es un juego tradicional donde explícitamente necesitas poner un while porque sino se cierra.

Comment: El problema definitivamente esta en como plateaste el problema en mi opinion no necesitas un doble ciclo, lo hiciste para validar cada pregunta pero entre el interval y los dos ciclo me es imposible seguir el error, puedo notar que el problema es que en la primera iteración solo revisa los valores hasta encontrar la pregunta pero después entra todas y cada una de las veces, ósea cambia los valores de la pregunta de A a Z tres veces antes de colocar A en la segunda ronda de saltar palabra, espero eso te ayude pero yo que tu replanteo el problema.